# How can I change visibility on radio button checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a figure like a cube but with 4 faces and all the faces are showing, but I want to hide the other 3 faces when one is showing

[image]

example : I've tried to set the opacity to 0 to other cube-sides when
the first radio button is checked but then it doesn't work to set the opacity to 1 again for the other cube-sides when other radio button is checked

I've tried in css but doesn't work as I expected. code:

```css
.cube-container {
  width: 22.5em;
  height: 28em;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 45em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(20deg);
}

.cube-side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8.1px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8.1px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
}

.cube-side:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(11.25em);
}

.cube-side:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(11.25em);
}

.cube-side:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(11.25em);
}

.cube-side:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(11.25em);
}

.radio-button {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.radio-button:checked~.cube {
  transition-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.radio-button:nth-child(1):checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.radio-button:nth-child(2):checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.radio-button:nth-child(3):checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.radio-button:nth-child(4):checked~.cube {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube-container">
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="cube-gallery" checked/>
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="cube-gallery" />
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="cube-gallery" />
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="cube-gallery" />
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="cube-side"><h1>Side 1</h1></div>
    <div class="cube-side"><h1>Side 2</h1></div>
    <div class="cube-side"><h1>Side 3</h1></div>
    <div class="cube-side"><h1>Side 4</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I want: **when .radio-button:nth-child(1):checked => hide the other cube-sides**

Comment: *"check the image"* - I don't see any image ! Overall, the wanted result is not that clear, providing some clarification would help greatly.

Comment: Your snippet appears to work - that is, when I click a radio button the 'cube' rotates until that face is full on and the other faces are not visible. What browser/OS are you using and can you show a picture of what it looks like for you?

Comment: I've uploaded the image. The other faces are still visibile ( I want them to be hidden or opacity = 0 )

Comment: The code is showing shadows of the headers on the other sides. I assume OP wants that to no longer show when the rotation completes

Comment: So your faces are transparent, right? So? How do you expect to transition the cube-side's content to opacity 0 in a meaningful way? Gradually? Magically? On transition end? On transition start? **Makes no sense**, sorry. Clipping would be a solution but I don't see how to implement it in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, adding the following CSS should do what you are asking:

```
.radio-button:nth-child(1):not(:checked)~div.cube div.cube-side:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio-button:nth-child(2):not(:checked)~div.cube div.cube-side:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio-button:nth-child(3):not(:checked)~div.cube div.cube-side:nth-child(3) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio-button:nth-child(4):not(:checked)~div.cube div.cube-side:nth-child(4) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Please, let me know if this worked and if not.

Comment: that's a pretty ugly way to approach the requested. Actually I see no other *"nice"* way to do it besides some sort of "clipping".